# Major product of isomerization reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, alcohols, carbocation, rearrangements

I am trying to come up with a logical mechanism for the following transformation, where 2-methylenecyclobutan-1-ol is converted to cyclopentanone under acidic conditions:

[image: Acid-catalysed rearrangement of 2-methylenecyclobutan-1-ol to cyclopentanone]

What I have tried to do was contract the ring to a methylcyclopropyl carbocation as it is exceptionally stable. I also tried to expand the ring but got an unsaturated primary alcohol instead. Can somebody suggest a proper mechanism for the reaction?

Comment: According to [*J. Chem. Soc., Chem. Commun.* **1973,** Vol. 4, 103–104](https://doi.org/10.1039/C39730000103): *"On heating in a sealed tube at 245° for 4 h or on treatment with 5% H2SO4 at 100°
for 30 min, (3)* [your starting material] *is quantitatively converted into **1-methylcyclopropanecarbaldehyde**."* This makes a lot more sense mechanistically, and is similar to a pinacol rearrangement: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdU5b.png

Comment: @orthocresol Yep, this is in agreement with what I know. Can you provide a more detailed explanation of this mechanism , and why it is the only correct one in the form of an answer?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/48739/mechanism-for-ring-contraction-from-2-methylenecyclobutanol-to-1-methylcycloprop